# Separation of files in the angular

Tags: angular, file-structure

I create a site on the angular
I have an admin part and a client
And such a situation arose
When entering the client part - the user downloads js files, which also apply to the administrative part, which seems wrong to me
Are there any ways to split files?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This discussion might help, Angular Guards + lazy loading can prevent non admin users from downloading the admin module.

[Angular - Are admin files downloadable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717180/angular-are-admin-files-downloadable/)